# how to configure nginx plus to serve Live HLS (not VOD)

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming

I am not able to configure latest nginx plus to stream LIVE HLS (not VOD), it seems that hls module only perform VOD HLS functionality! if I supplied m3u8 playlist without

```
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

it won't work. I found that its only capable of generating m3u8 on the fly from mp4 files. I can't use rtmp module as described in nginx docs. I want to nginx plus to serve and play live m3u8 playlist that contain 3 ts segments where the playlist doesn't end with:

```
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

how can I accomplish that?

**Update**

with @aergistal help, it seems nginx plus is not required to stream live m3u8 playlist, in which I removed

> hls;

from location config, and it does serve m3u8 live ts segments just fine.

as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

> Nginx Plus:   VOD HLS as origin

so I guess the OpenSource Nginx version is enough to handle my requirements.

**Edit:** adding m3u8 content (located in path /usr/share/nginx/html/hls/t.m3u8), fstab entry, nginx config

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:719727873
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:629987@1809876
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2015-08-13T10:54:29.523000Z
#HP-DTS:6890675118
#HP-IFRAMES:6890718318,6890761518,6890804718,6890847918,6890891118
#EXTINF:2,
mnt/win/Video/143/9/463262/bms_VIDEO_ENG_1439463262.ts?range=bytes=1809876-2439863
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:667211@2439864
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2015-08-13T10:54:31.923000Z
#HP-DTS:6890891118
#HP-IFRAMES:6890934318,6890977518,6891020718,6891063918,6891107118
#EXTINF:2,
mnt/win/Video/143/9/463262/bms_VIDEO_ENG_1439463262.ts?range=bytes=2439864-3107075
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:593515@3107076
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2015-08-13T10:54:34.323000Z
#HP-DTS:6891107118
#HP-IFRAMES:6891150318,6891193518,6891236718,6891279918,6891323118
#EXTINF:2,
mnt/win/Video/143/9/463262/bms_VIDEO_ENG_1439463262.ts?range=bytes=3107076-3700591
```

fstab entry (just for reference)

```
//172.18.1.12/bms /usr/share/nginx/html/hls/mnt/win cifs user,uid=500,rw,suid,username=administrator,password=x 0 0
```

nginx config server block:

```
server {
           listen 888;

           # Path for static files
           root /usr/share/nginx/html;
           location  /hls {
           }

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to configure it, you just write the segments and playlist into a web accessible directory. You can set the mime-types and headers in a `location` block. Nginx won't *create* a live stream for you however, you need to use something else like FFmpeg to output the segments/playlist.

Comment: @aergistal thanks, I am not facing issue with segments and playlist generation. the problem is that when I try to open the link http://x.x.x.x/hls/live.m3u8 in vlc or ios, its not opening! but if i try open file.mp4.m3u8 it works!

Comment: Do you have an error code/message? Check the nginx `error.log` or the VLC console output.

Comment: @aergistal thanks again, it seems my location config invalid as per nginx error.log, I will test with valid config tomorrow as I left office now.

Comment: @aergistal it worked on iOS, but vlc failed to play the playlist if ts end with "?range=bytes=3107076-3700591"  if i removed that from the playlist, it work in VLC, so why nginx/vlc consider "?range=bytes=3107076-3700591" part of the ts file name?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your live `m3u8` playlist in the original question please? Why are you using byte range like this, do you want to live stream using HLS version 3 instead of 4 which added support for byte-ranges?

Comment: @aergistal I did edit with adding  m3u8 content, fstab entry, nginx config. yes I am using version 4 of m3u8 specs. please add an answer and confirm my findings that nginx plus is not required to serve ts and m3u8 files in case it being generated in backend using tools such ffmpeg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nginx Plus** supports adaptive streaming for [video-on-demand only](https://www.nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/) using `Apple HLS` or `Adobe HDS`. Alternatively you can create a `HLS Live` stream using an `RTMP` input with the [Nginx RTMP Module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) (also works on the basic version of Nginx).

While Nginx won't *create* a Live `HLS` stream you can still serve `HLS` created by another tool such as `ffmpeg` since it uses `HTTP`.

This works out-of-the-box even in the free version of Nginx, without the need to configure anything.

Optionally, you can manually add the MIME types or add particular headers (eg. cache-control, CORS):

```
location /hls {
      root /path/to/root;

      types {
           application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
           video/mp2t ts;
      }

      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
}
```

Comment: Hi @aergistal
Can you answer/comment on my qn?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117072/right-or-practical-way-to-ingest-multiple-rtmp-streams-and-push-hls-to-many-view

Sorry couldn't find any other way to ask you